# Howto NOT escape a string function parameter in python

Tags: python, function, parameters, escaping, os.path

To cut a long story short.
I have this function:

```
def save_screenshot(self, file_destination, picture_format = None)
    file_path_name, file_extension = os.path.splitext(file_destination)
    file_path, file_name = os.path.split(file_path_name)
    (...)
```

Now, I call the function like this:

```
save_screenshot("C:\Temp\picture.jpg", "JPG")
```

I know howto NOT escape a string in python (with the help of "os.path.join"), but I don't know howto do this, if the string is a function parameter. The function works fine (on a windows), if I write "C:\\Temp\\picture.jpg" or "C:/Temp/picture.jpg".

Would be great, if you have some advice.

thanks

Comment: Do you want to read the path from console? I don't quite seem to understand what is your goal here.

Comment: You can use raw string, e.g. `r"C:\Temp\picture.jpg"`.

Comment: @DJV: No, not from console. Everything is included in a script without any request during the script.

Comment: @eljobso Then [SaCry's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15134710/1974792) is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned you could use:

Raw String r" string "

```
save_screenshot(r"C:\Temp\picture.jpg", "JPG")
```

It should also be possible to use """ string """

```
save_screenshot("""C:\Temp\picture.jpg""", "JPG")
```

Maybe I could also reference to this answer on Stack:
[what-exactly-do-u-and-rstring-flags..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-rstring-flags-in-python-and-what-are-raw-string-litte)

This basically explains how to use raw string literals in order to ignore escape sequences that derive from backslashes in Strings (mostly for regexp).

Answer (score 0):

I thing your problem is not using os.path rather then escape/unescape string.
Would this function better?

```
def save_screenshot(self, file_destination, picture_format = None):
    file_name = os.path.basename(file_destination)
    path = os.path.dirname(file_destination)
    base, ext = os.path.splitext(file_name)
    e = ext if picture_format is None else '.%s' % picture_format.lower()
    to_path = os.path.join(path, base + e)
    print(to_path)
```